# How to prevent Html.fromHtml from trimming whitespace

Tags: java, android, removing-whitespace

In an Android Java project, I have a string like this one (although with varying amounts of whitespace on either side):

```
String foo = "  foo bar  "
```

The whitespace on the two sides of the string is important, as the actual string contains indented code with HTML syntax highlighting.

When I pass the string through `Html.fromHtml`, this start and end whitespace is removed, but I need to keep the whitespace there:

```
Html.fromHtml(foo).toString() // "foo bar" - I want "  foo bar  "
```

How I can preserve the whitespace on the sides of the string through the `Html.fromHtml` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For preserving starting whitespace, this Kotlin code appears to work, and probably wouldn't be difficult to adapt for working with ending whitespace either:

```
fun replaceWithNonBreakingAtStart(str: String) = (1..(str.takeWhile { it == ' ' }.count())).map { "&nbsp;" }.joinToString("") + str.trimStart()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Using TextUtils.htmlEncode(str).

This method will escape all html string character.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#htmlEncode(java.lang.String)

Comment: This looks like it's worth a go - I'll try it when I can. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - it just keeps the spaces as spaces. Thanks though.

Comment: well, then try 
`foo = foo.replaceAll(" ", "&nbsp;");`
this surely replace space to &nbsp;
If you want replace all white space (include space and tab) try `foo = foo.replaceAll("\\s", "&nbsp;");`

Comment: The issue with that is that my real string may contain HTML which needs to be rendered, so `<font color="red">` would become `<font&nbsp;color="red">` which wouldn't render.

Comment: hmm..i think wrap string with CDATA might work. 
e.g. ```foo = String.format("<![CDATA[%s]]>", foo);``` @OrangeFlash81

Answer (score 0):

As `Html.fromHtml()` parses the string as html tags and content may be you want to use the encoded character for space which is `&nbsp;`

try this in your code

```
String foo = "  foo bar&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

Note: repeat `&nbsp;` as many spaces as you need to show.

**Edit:**
if you are getting your string from somewhere else, you can replace spaces with `&nbsp;` before passing it

```
String foo = getMyFoo();
foo = foo.replaceAll(" ","&nbsp;");
```

Comment: I can't really do this - the string is dynamically generated, my `foo` was just an example. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 you can use `replaceAll()`, check my Edit

Answer (score 0):

Yazan's suggestion was sufficient,but since you said that the string is generated dynamically,you can always take the newly generated string s for example and use the concat() method.For example s.concat(" &nbsp");